# Efficient element-wise multiplication of a matrix and a vector in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, tensor

What would be the most efficient way to multiply (element-wise) a 2D tensor (matrix):

```
x11 x12 .. x1N
...
xM1 xM2 .. xMN
```

by a vertical vector:

```
w1
...
wN
```

to obtain a new matrix:

```
x11*w1 x12*w2 ... x1N*wN
...
xM1*w1 xM2*w2 ... xMN*wN
```

To give some context, we have `M` data samples in a batch that can be processed in parallel, and each `N`-element sample must be multiplied by weights `w` stored in a variable to eventually pick the largest `Xij*wj` for each row `i`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The simplest code to do this relies on the broadcasting behavior of [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply)<sup>*</sup>, which is based on [numpy's broadcasting behavior](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
x = tf.constant(5.0, shape=[5, 6])
w = tf.constant([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
xw = tf.multiply(x, w)
max_in_rows = tf.reduce_max(xw, 1)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(xw)
# ==> [[0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0],
#      [0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0],
#      [0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0],
#      [0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0],
#      [0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0]]

print sess.run(max_in_rows)
# ==> [25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0]
```

<sup>*</sup> In older versions of TensorFlow, `tf.multiply()` was called `tf.mul()`. You can also use the `*` operator (i.e. `xw = x * w`) to perform the same operation.

Comment: The link for the Documentation is dead. This is the actual one : [tf.multiply](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply)

Comment: don't forget the parenthesis:print(sess.run(xw)) and print(sess.run(max_in_rows))

Comment: i applied this to a dense matrix and a sparse vector, which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As @mrry pointed out, `__mul__` (aka `*`) does the job, e.g. `x * w`.

I just want to point out that `tf.multiply()` and `__mul__()` behave differently if the matrix is sparse because `__mul__` does dense to sparse broadcasting under the hood.

An example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.sparse.from_dense(tf.constant(5.0, shape=[5, 6]))  # SparseTensor
w = tf.constant([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])           # EagerTensor


tf.multiply(x, w)            # <---- error

xw = x * w                   # <--- OK
xw = tf.sparse.to_dense(xw)  # convert into an EagerTensor if desired
```

However, if the vector is sparse, `*` wouldn't work because as stated before, the broadcasting is only from the dense side to the sparse side. The simplest way in this case is probably to convert the vector into a dense vector and multiply 2 dense tensors.

```py
x = tf.constant(5.0, shape=[5, 6])
w = tf.sparse.from_dense(tf.constant([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]))

xw = tf.multiply(x, tf.sparse.to_dense(w))
#                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   <---- convert to a dense tensor
```